# Timestamp MySQL is substracting two hours of my date

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, timestamp

I am adding information to a database and when I want to set the Timestamp (d2) on the PreparedStatement (stmt) the hour of the date is decremented on 2 hours. See the code and the output:

```
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
            con = ds.getConnection();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+machines.get(0)+ "("+Information.variables.get(0)+","+Information.variables.get(1)+","+Information.variables.get(2)+
                    ","+Information.variables.get(3)+","+Information.variables.get(4)+","+Information.variables.get(5)+","+Information.variables.get(6)+","+Information.variables.get(7)+","+Information.variables.get(8)+
                    ","+Information.variables.get(9)+","+Information.variables.get(10)+","+Information.variables.get(11)+") VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

            String s = info.Data();
            Date d = transformStringToDate(s);
            System.out.println(d);
            java.sql.Timestamp d2 = new java.sql.Timestamp(d.getTime());
            stmt.setTimestamp(1, d2);
            System.out.println(d2);
            
            stmt.setDouble(2, info.Pes_programat());
            stmt.setDouble(3, info.Pes_real());
            stmt.setDouble(4, info.Pes_maxim());
            stmt.setDouble(5, info.Pes_minim());
            stmt.setInt(6, info.Marxa());
            stmt.setDouble(7, info.Incidencia());
            stmt.setDouble(8, info.Contador_de_coixins());
            stmt.setDouble(9, info.Producte());
            stmt.setDouble(10, info.Fibra());
            stmt.setDouble(11, info.Pes_funda());
            stmt.setDouble(12, info.Mides_funda());
            System.out.println(stmt);
            stmt.execute();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
            try {
                    if(stmt != null) stmt.close();
                    if(con != null) con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

This is the output of the System.out.println():

> Fri Jun 15 18:55:53 CEST 2018
>
> 2018-06-15 18:55:53.0
>
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: INSERT INTO m1(Data,Pes_programat,Pes_real,Pes_maxim,Pes_minim,Marxa,Incidencia,Contador_de_coixins,Producte,Fibra,Pes_funda,Mides_funda) VALUES ( '2018-06-15 16:55:53.0', 211.0, 11.98, 2.15, 1.85, 1, 0.0, 151.0, 1.0, 2.0, 50.0, 190.0)

The first date type Date is correct, and also the Timestamp d2 variable. But when I call stmt.setTimestamp it put the hour decremented on 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CEST is 2 hours ahead of UTC. That's causing the difference.

Comment: Oh that's true. Thank you